# Spring MVC: Dynamically added checkboxes not submitting

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I have a form that dynamically generates checkboxes based on the user's selection in a different part of the form. These checkboxes appear on screen and behave normally, but when the form is submitted, they are never included in the request. Essentially, it behaves as if the checkbox elements aren't bound to the model object.

Here is the backing object. The field the checkboxes are supposed to bind to is 'stores':

```
public class GameplanGrouping {
private int id;
private Dba dba;
private String name;
private Set<String> stores = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Here is what the relevant parts of the form look like, once it's all generated:

```
<form id="createCategory" action="/gameplan/newGrouping" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
...
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="store_0" name="stores" value="13950" class="storeCheckBox"/>13950
</td>
```

And here is the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"/newGrouping"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String submitAddGrouping(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @Valid @ModelAttribute("gameplanGrouping") GameplanGrouping grouping){
   gpDao.insertGameplanGrouping(grouping);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "Successfully added new grouping '" + grouping.getName() + "' for division " + grouping.getDba().getName() + ".");
          return "redirect:/groupings?division=" + grouping.getDba().getName();
      }
```

All of the other bindings (e.g. to 'name' and 'dba') work fine, but the Set of Stores is never populated.

The weird thing is that, if I copy one of the generated checkboxes and insert it manually into the HTML, it does bind and report the values correctly. For instance, if I add:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="store_dummy" name="stores" value="DUMMY" class="storeCheckBox"/>
DUMMY</td>
```

to the table before the cell filled with the generated results and select it, then "DUMMY" appears as one of the values of "stores" in the backing object when I submit. Why is it bound in the one case but not in the case of the dynamically generated element?

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, I switched the Set to a List because Spring won't bind to a Set, but that didn't help either. The behavior was identical.

However, I note with interest that the version of Spring MVC packaged as part of Spring Boot 1.3.6 apparently *can* bind to Sets, as demonstrated below:[image]

As mentioned above, however, I can only get this to bind when I code the checkbox elements in manually. It does not bind under any circumstances with the JQuery generated markup.

Comment: Obvious question: are they actually selected?

Comment: @Alan Hay Yes, they are.

Comment: You cannot bind to a Set only to a Map, List or Array. Try changing to List<String> stores. See also https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that, but it still doesn't bind. Also, there may be something different about the newest version of Spring, because it did bind to the Set<String> field when I used a non-dynamically generated element. I mentioned this peculiarity in the last paragraph.

Comment: You say that "then "DUMMY" appears as one of the values of "stores" in the HTTPServletRequest" which is  not the same as it being subsequently bound to the Model objects 'stores' field by Spring.

Comment: @AlanHay Well said. I updated the question and provided some evidence that the most recent version of Spring MVC does indeed map to the model object even when it's a Set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125031/discussion-between-mike-dibaggio-and-alan-hay).